# Fatal Error. Как решить проблему?

Tags: php

у меня ошибка

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 81 bytes) in
>   /home/ssumk/public_html/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php on
>   line 811.

Как можно ее исправить? На сервере выделяют 256М. Вот код:

```
protected function fetchObject($cursor = null, $class = 'stdClass') 
{
    return mysqli_fetch_object($cursor ? $cursor : $this->cursor, $class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Укажите просто `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` и не будет лимита на память. Почитать подробнее [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: Если сервер ограниченную память дает, то как настройки приложения уберут этот лимит?

Comment: поменять в php.ini